# How to change the kedro configuration environment in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, kedro

I want to run a kedro pipeline in the base env using jupyter notebook. I do this the following way:

```py
%reload_kedro --env=base
session.run(pipeline_name='dpfm1')
```

Doing this, the `%reload_kedro` command raises the following error:

```py
RuntimeError: Could not find the project configuration file 'pyproject.toml' in --env=base. If you have created 
your project with Kedro version <0.17.0, make sure to update your project template. See 
https://github.com/kedro-org/kedro/blob/main/RELEASE.md#migration-guide-from-kedro-016-to-kedro-0170 for how to 
migrate your Kedro project.
```

However, I have installed kedro version 0.18.2:

```py
>>>!kedro --version
kedro, version 0.18.2
```

What's the matter here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ilja This is mentioned in the RELEASE.md if you have an old Kedro project, i.e. 0.16.x, there is no `pypropject.toml` file.

You may have Kedro 0.18.2 installed, but if it is an old project, there are some migration steps that you need to take, which are included in the RELEASE.md

If it is a new project, it's likely that you are not providing the right `path` argument, kedro need to find the `pyproject.toml` for certain metadata and determine where is the project root.

p.s. `%reload_kedro path --env --extra_params` is only supported since 0.18.3, previously it does not support any argument other than `path`, so you may to upgrade your Kedro version.

Comment: I have a `pyproject.toml` file, so I think the problem is that I can't pass any arguments other than `path` to `%reload_kedro` in version 0.18.2.